# Qualtrics -- Uppercase open end text

Tags: javascript, uppercase, qualtrics

I would like to text entered into an open box (or specify box) to be automatically uppercased. The script I have below sort of works. To get it to work I have to the next question and then come back. I need it work on the actually question itself. Thanks for your assistance.

```html
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/
    var input = $("QR~" + this.questionId);
    var text = ('${q://QID1/ChoiceTextEntryValue}');
    input.value = text.toUpperCase();


    input.on('blur', function repopulate() {
        input.setChoiceValue(input.value, true);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your blur line with this:

```
input.on('change', () => input.value = input.value.toUpperCase());
```

`blur` only triggers when the element goes out of focus, but you want it to be triggered whenever a change occurs.

Comment: Now to work on getting to function on other specify type responses.

Comment: When answers work for you, please upvote/Accept them to mark the questions as solved.